# When should I delete temporary image files?

Tags: android, performance, temporary-files

At some point in my app, I have to save some temporary image files. I've tried using `file.deleteOnExit()`, after some research I found out it does not ensure the file will be actually deleted. So I tried to follow one of the alternatives listed on `deleteOnExit()` documentation that says:

> • Maintain your own set of files to delete, and process it at an appropriate point in your application's lifecycle.

I am wondering, what is this appropriate point? I've tried to delete a set of files on `application.onTerminate()`, but the result is the same, if the app process is killed, it'll never reach `onTerminate()` method.

In order to keep performance and delete temporary files safely, when (where) should I place my code to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you are sure you won't use them, but no sooner.

More seriously, you should store them in the cache directory. You can get that with `Context.getCacheDir()`. That way if your cleanup methods don't end up getting called, the user can delete them from the Applications menu, or the system may delete them if space is required.

You can (and should) try to delete them in `onDestroy()` or even `onPause()`, depending on your implementation, but those are also not guaranteed to be called.

You might also put a timestamp in the filename, and run a cleanup periodically with `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` by comparing the filename (which should reflect the last time that file was accessed, ideally) with the current time, and deleting it if the difference is greater than some constant. For performance sake I would probably run this daily or a couple times a day, and also (in a background thread) when the app opens or the relevant activity starts.